Tangent space - Example from "Vector Calculus", Baxandall, Liebeck
There seems to be a minor issue here (on the last line).
Right?

This is on pages 129, 130 from the book
https://www.amazon.com/Vector-Calculus-Dover-Books-Mathematics/dp/0486466205/
I think on the last line we should have
$x_4 = 2p_1x_1 + 2p_2x_2 + 2p_3x_3 - (p_1^2 + p_2^2 + p_3^2) $
These twos (the multipliers) seem to be missing.
Also, I have a conceptual question: is this tangent space what's called a hyper-plane, i.e. is it a $(m-1)$-dimensional subspace of $\mathbb{R}^m$? If so, I think we can say here that the tangent space is a hyperplane. That hyperplane would contain the point $(p, f(p))$ and would have the equation given here (3.4.10). Correct?
But I wonder... can it also happen that this tangent space has dimension $(m-2)$ for example, say when the coefficient in front of $(x_1 - p_1)$ is zero. I am just somewhat confused about this tangent subspace concept. Does it always have dimension $(m-1)$ or is it $\le (m-1)$?
And can we always call it a hyperplane?

Indeed it seems there is a mistake. Are you asking for confirmation?

@Zima Yes, but also I have that conceptual question at the end of the post.

With this pedestrian definition of tangent space it is always $(m-1)$-dimensional. To obtain a $(m-2)$-dimensional tangent space you could take two functions $f,g$ whose graphs intersect in a way so that their $(m-1)$-dimensional tangent spaces intersect in a common $(m-2)$-dimensional one. I recommend Desmos to visualize some examples.
